# Integrated Windows Auth (NTLM) on a Mac using Google Chrome or Safari

Tags: macos, google-chrome, iis-7, ntlm

An IIS7 Intranet site with Windows Authentication enabled. When hit from Chrome on windows the pass-through authentication works fine (no User / Password prompt), however, Chrome on a Mac you get a prompt. Since the internal network uses CAC/PKI no one has a password.

I've tried toggling the Windows Authentication on the site to negotiate, but same user/pass prompt.

```
appcmd set config /section:windowsAuthentication /-providers.[value='Negotiate']
```

Anyone know a solution for Chrome on OS X?

*EDIT*

OS X 10.6.8

Centrify for Mac will be used to authenticate to the (Windows 2008 R2 ActiveDirectory) network via CAC.

*EDIT 2*

There is a proxy setup, but it gets bypassed for local intranet sites, so I don't think it is playing a role.

Also tried using the **--auth-server-whitelist** command line switch, didn't work.

*EDIT 3*

**SOLUTION**

```
open 'Google Chrome.app' --args --auth-server-whitelist="*DOMAIN.TLD" --auth-negotiate-delegate-whitelist="*DOMAIN.TLD" --auth-schemes="digest,ntlm,negotiate"
```

Unfortunately Google Chrome for Mac has no way of specifying command line arguments on every load, so some sort of shell script will need to be made.

**Running the following shell script at log in was the final solution to get around Chrome updates and extra doc icons.**

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/
if [ -f 'Google Chrome.bin' ];
then
   echo "Already Modified"
else
   sudo chmod u+wr ./
   sudo mv 'Google Chrome' 'Google Chrome.bin'
   sudo echo "#!/bin/bash" > "Google Chrome"
   sudo echo 'exec /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome.bin --args --auth-server-whitelist="*DOMAIN.TLD" --auth-negotiate-delegate-whitelist="*DOMAIN.TLD" --auth-schemes="digest,ntlm,negotiate"' >> "Google Chrome"
   sudo chmod a+x 'Google Chrome'
   echo "NTLM Will now work in chrome"
fi
```

Comment: you don't provide enough information on how the Macs authenticate on the network... there are several dependencies - for example which OSX version you are using etc. - in the current state your question can't be answered :-(

Comment: @Yahia - I updated the question, hopefully now it can be answered without having to make assumptions.

Comment: From what I gather what you want might be impossible. BUT to be on the safe side I would strongly recommend to ask the vendor of Centrify - perhaps they have some sort of "single-sign-on module for web applications" to help with this situation...

Comment: @Yahia - Is there a Mac+ChromeBrowser configuration that WOULD make this possible? Perhaps with something in-place of Centrify...

Comment: Any chance you could use OSX 10.7 ?

Comment: @Yahia - Yes... Does OSX 10.7 have some feature that improves windows auth compatibility?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't a bug at the moment. The Mac version of Chrome simply does not support/respect Kerberos policies ("Negotiate" Windows Authentication) unless the domain white-listed and the browser fired from the command line. See this link posted 10/31/2011:

http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=102339

It looks like you might be able to permanently white-list a domain though:

http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=592eb87350d9d528&hl=en

---

Since you have already tried the white-list switch, I looked closer and it is an OSX thing... 10.7 is necessary for the switch to work properly with Chrome. Your 10.6 version won't work without a third party tool like Centrify.

Not a happy answer, but the truth.

Answer (score 5):

It seems we can do the following configuration in Terminal,

```
$ defaults write com.google.Chrome AuthServerWhitelist "*.example.com"
$ defaults write com.google.Chrome AuthNegotiateDelegateWhitelist "*.example.com"
$ defaults write com.google.Chrome AuthSchemes "digest,ntlm,negotiate"
```

Answer (score 1):

`defaults write com.google.Chrome AuthServerWhitelist '<your domain>'` will permanently allow kerberos to a server or set of servers (*.mydomain.local).

Answer (score 0):

What version of Chrome? This was an active bug, make sure you've got the latest version. It  should work...

http://chromium.googlecode.com/issues/attachment?aid=-4050060571219819368&name=Prompt.png&token=NHQTVDWyO_jUXxWmvuzGnGer2sc%3A1325131426103&inline=1

http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=19

Comment: lol sidenote, the NTLM code comes from mozilla!

http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/net/http/http_auth_handler_ntlm.h?view=markup&pathrev=10667

Comment: It's the latest version of Chrome (auto update). It doesn't work with the OSX+Centrify config from my question.

Answer (score 0):

Integrated Windows Auth (NTLM) on a Mac using Safari:

1. Update krb5.conf

```
$ sudo nano /etc/krb5.conf

[logging]
 default = /var/log/krb5libs.log
 kdc = /var/log/krb5kdc.log
 admin_server = /var/log/kadmind.log

[libdefaults]
 dns_lookup_realm = true
 dns_lookup_kdc = true
 ticket_lifetime = 24h
 forwardable = yes
 default_realm = MY.DOMAIN
 udp_preference_limit = 1

[realms]

[domain_realm]

[appdefaults]
 pam = {
   debug = false
   ticket_lifetime = 36000
   renew_lifetime = 36000
   forwardable = true
   krb4_convert = false
 }
```

2. Run kinit command

```
$ kinit -V myuser

myuser@MY.DOMAIN's password:
Placing tickets for 'myuser@MY.DOMAIN' in cache 'API:redacted'
```

3. Access website via ***Safari***

Note: This used to work with chrome using the following commands but has recently stopped working - so now use Safari:

```
defaults write com.google.Chrome AuthServerWhitelist "*.MY.DOMAIN"
defaults write com.google.Chrome AuthNegotiateDelegateWhitelist "*.MY.DOMAIN"
defaults write com.google.Chrome AuthSchemes "digest,ntlm,negotiate"
```

Answer (score 0):

At this moment working solution is:

```
defaults write com.google.Chrome AuthServerAllowlist "*.MY.DOMAIN"
defaults write com.google.Chrome AuthNegotiateDelegateAllowlist "*.MY.DOMAIN"
defaults write com.google.Chrome AuthSchemes "digest,ntlm,negotiate"
```

And then u can check here chrome://policy/